# Is there an R.styleable for table row style?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, android-styles, tablerow

I am trying to set the style for a table row and table divider in Xamarin Android. I want the style to be set in AppTheme's style within Styles.xml so that I don't have to set the style of each individual table row in all my layouts. For example, I want something like "android:tableRowStyle" that I can assign within my AppTheme style. My AppTheme currently looks like this:

```
name="AppTheme"
parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item
  name="preferenceTheme">@style/preferenceTheme</item>
<item
  name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
<item
  name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextViewStyle</item>
<item
  name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item
  name="android:popupTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
```

Researching brought me to Android's list of `R.styleable` elements but I could not find anything related to table views or table elements. I've also looked at the TableRow documentation and don't see a way to set the style attributes other than directly in the layout or programmatically.

Does anyone know a way to specify an app wide table row and table divider style? Thanks!